# Unable to read a shadow dom element using js Executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, shadow-dom

I have been trying to automate the Service Now Website and the elements of the website are in the shadow DOM.
Website: https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do

Figured out how to interact with the shadow elements with the help of js Executor, but now I got this error for one of the elements:

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')

Here's the code snippet:

```
   Thread.sleep(5);
     String startBuilding = "document.querySelector('body > dps-
    app').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > main > dps-home-auth-
    quebec').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > section:nth-child(1) > div > dps-page-header > div:nth-child(1) > button > span').click()";
    js.executeScript(startBuilding);
```

Can somebody help me resolve this?

PS: I'm a noob in Selenium.

Tried waits and Thread.sleep() as well, yet it didn't work.

Comment: You've edited and removed your code? Why? Please include the code the you've tried?

Comment: Yeah I have attached it now, I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you logged in ? It looks like your class `dps-home-auth-quebec` is only available for logged in users.

Comment: @demouser123 yes I'm automating right from the sign in process, so the login process is complete right?

Comment: Unfortunately without the piece of HTML code, I can't help you because this site requires a login and I don't have one. If you can add the HTML, then I can give it a shot.

Comment: Oh I'm not using HTML, but what I can give you is my code of automation in Selenium, with my user credentials. Would that help? @demouser123

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_content')
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain about this, as I'm new to this? How do I find which is the shadow host and shadow content?

Comment: If you are using selenium 4, you can directly use shadow_root method to get the shadow dom content and later access to specific content. If you share the html structure I will be able to provide working example.

Comment: Sure here's the tag that I'm trying to access in the shadow dom:  `<div id="d6e462a5c3533010cbd77096e940dd8c" role="button" class="sn-polaris-tab can-animate polaris-enabled" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="All" unpinnedleft="194" style="position: absolute; margin-inline-end: 0px; left: 194px;">All</div>`